# Could not load configuration file

Tags: unity-game-engine, configuration, opc, opc-ua

I am trying to implement OPC UA client in Unity. But I am getting an `ServiceResultException: Could not load configuration file.` expection in line `application.LoadApplicationConfiguration("ConsoleReferenceClient.Config.xml", false).Wait();`
which means the "Config.xml" file couldn't be loaded in Unity. But the same program works perfectly in console application. **How can I load the configuration file in unity?**

```
void Start()
    {
        // Define the UA Client application
        ApplicationInstance application = new ApplicationInstance();
            application.ApplicationName = "Quickstart Console Reference Client";
            application.ApplicationType = ApplicationType.Client;
        

        // load the application configuration.
        application.LoadApplicationConfiguration("Assets/ConsoleReferenceClient.Config.xml", false).Wait();
            // check the application certificate.
            application.CheckApplicationInstanceCertificate(false, 0).Wait();

            // create the UA Client object and connect to configured server.
            Quickstarts.ConsoleReferenceClient.UAClient uaClient = new Quickstarts.ConsoleReferenceClient.UAClient(application.ApplicationConfiguration);

            if (uaClient.Connect())
            {
                uaClient.ReadNodes();
                //uaClient.WriteNodes();
                uaClient.Browse();
                //uaClient.CallMethod();
                uaClient.SubscribeToDataChanges();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000);

                uaClient.Disconnect();
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Could not connect to server!");
            }
            Debug.Log("\nProgram ended.");
            Debug.Log("Press any key to finish...");
            Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

**Exception**:

```
ServiceResultException: Could not load configuration file.
Opc.Ua.Configuration.ApplicationInstance+<LoadApplicationConfiguration>d__33.MoveNext () (at <1c5dac388c934c65a66a1f12b206c16d>:0)
Rethrow as AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional (System.Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) (at <fb001e01371b4adca20013e0ac763896>:0)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait (System.Int32 millisecondsTimeout, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) (at <fb001e01371b4adca20013e0ac763896>:0)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait () (at <fb001e01371b4adca20013e0ac763896>:0)
TestClient.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/TestClient.cs:25)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if `ConsoleReferenceClient.Config.xml` is copied into output folder of your unity project. Then check the location of your executable, because the relative path (first parameter of `LoadApplicationConfiguration` method) needs to point from executable to config file).